# INSERT INTO statement won't insert a specific value correctly?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, innodb, mariadb

I am trying to use the INSERT INTO SQL statement in php. It will input everything correctly up until the last value (`$bands_bio`). Instead of putting in the correct information, it leaves the value blank. I have looked over everything and can't seem to find any sort of syntax errors.

```
$page_title = "Create a new band";

require ('includes/database.php');
require_once 'includes/bandsHeader.php';

$band_name = $conn->real_escape_string(trim(filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'band_name', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)));
$band_photo = $conn->real_escape_string(trim(filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'band_photo', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)));
$genre = $conn->real_escape_string(trim(filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'genre', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)));
$band_bio = $conn->real_escape_string(trim(filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'band_bio', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)));

echo $band_bio;

if (($band_name === "") OR ($genre === "") OR ($band_photo === "") OR ($band_bio = "")) {
    $errno = $conn->errno;
    $errmsg = $conn->error;
    echo "<div id='contentWrapper'>";
    echo "<div class='contentBox'>";
    echo "Insertion failed with: ($errno) $errmsg<br/>\n";
    echo "</div></div>";
    $conn->close();
    include 'includes/searchFooter.php';
    exit;
}

$albums = 0;

$sql = "INSERT INTO bands VALUES (NULL, '$band_name', '$genre', '$albums', '$band_bio')";

$query = @$conn->query($sql);

if (!$query) {
    $errno = $conn->errno;
    $errmsg = $conn->error;
    echo "<div id='contentWrapper'>";
    echo "<div class='contentBox'>";
    echo "Insertion failed with: ($errno) $errmsg<br/>\n";
    echo "</div></div>";
    $conn->close();
    include 'includes/footer.php';
    exit;
}
```

As you can see, I echoed out `$band_bio` in order to see if it was getting the right value from my form that uses the GET method, which it is so that's not the issue. It has no problem inserting everything correctly up until the last value, which is supposed to be the last column called `band_bio` in my `bands` table in my database. It will not output any errors or anything, either. It's almost as if it's taking the string data from the variable and removing all of the text before it inserts the information.

I have been working on this website for a few weeks now and have used the INSERT INTO statement the exact same way on other pages and it works just fine. This is the first thing that has really stumped me and I can't figure it out. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What's the ddl (schema) for your `bands` table?

Comment: What eggmatters said + example values you insert, if possible :)

Comment: Could it be: `$bands_bio = "'');DELETE from bands where true'"`?

Comment: CREATE TABLE `bands` (
      `band_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `band_name` text NOT NULL,
      `genre` text NOT NULL,
      `numof_albums` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `band_bio` text NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

My bad I don't know how to format comments haha

Comment: band bio is likely being set as member id.

Comment: @vuryss I assigned the values to variables using the real_escape_string method, grabbing the associated inputs from a form using the get method. I only used strings for all of them in this case. So example values would just be any string you can imagine haha.

Comment: @eggmatters That would be the case had I not posted the wrong ddl at first by accident

Comment: General word of advice: Get rid of those calls to real_escape_string and enter the world of parameters: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: @GolezTrol Could you show me an example of how I would use those in this instance?

Comment: @GolezTrol I already did my work, you're the one who suggested to change something I already wrote that works just fine. But ok.

Comment: It was just an advice which *might* take your database development to a next level, and I provided it with a link that already contains a bunch of examples, which you can't possibly have read in the 1.5 minutes between my comment and your reply. So no, I'm not going to provide a specific example for this case, because this case is just like any other case. If you don't want to dive into it, please do stick with `real_escape_string`. No hard feelings. It'll work just fine.

Comment: @GolezTrol Understood, sorry for the misunderstanding. I know you're trying to help, I guess I just got hasty and didn't want to dive into something that I didn't necessarily need at the moment. A lot of the things I have written are things I self-taught myself how to do for hours and hours because that's what my education encourages, so I have no problem looking into how to do something and doing my own work. No hard feelings. I'll look into parameters when I get the chance because I'm always eager to learn more. :)

Comment: @GolezTrol Ah, I see. So parameters and prepared statements offer additional security from SQL injection by completely separating the data from the instructions and eliminating the possibility of accidentally forgetting to make a call to `real_escape_string`. That really is handy. Thanks for informing me about it. :)

Comment: Jup, security, ease of use (once you're used to it), and in some cases better performance. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When inserting, ensure that your pk (id) field is set to auto-increment. 
This way, you can exert more control over your queries. You should be more successful with:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO bands "
 . "(`band_name`,`genre`,`numof_albums`,`band_bio`) "
 . "VALUES ('$band_name', '$genre', '$albums', '$band_bio')";
```

By not specifying the pk field, INNODB will automatically increment and insert it for you.

The idea is that you want to specify which columns are being inserted into. Relying on column ordering by mysql is fine, but there may be something at play in your case.

There should be no reason why band_bio would be "left off". You would get a column-mismatch error.

Comment: Yeah, I have the primary key set to be auto-incremented. My whole website would break if that weren't the case as it relies heavily on the primary key and foreign key association through band_id...also I accidentally included an old schema by accident at first. The correct one was edited in.

Comment: I edited my answer. Did you have any success with the query from above?

Comment: I tried using your query and it returned this error: Insertion failed with: (1064) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '0' at line 1

Comment: Does it log the query? (IM me with the entry) (nm, the query above is wrong. Edited to use the PHP string concatenation operator. Not javascript ;)

Comment: I didn't even notice that either. Switching between php and JavaScript/jQuery all the time myself, I feel your pain. Your current query does the exact same thing as my original one does...it inserts all the infortmation into the correct fields except for band_bio. Perhaps it's an issue with the DBMS itself?

Comment: I do have a separate application that edits the values in the bands table using the sql UPDATE statement. That works perfectly fine when it comes to editing the data for the band_bio column. I really am stumped with this one. You're right, there should be no reason that band_bio is getting left off. I think it might be a bug?

Comment: Found the problem, it was a stupid misused operator. I can't believe we both missed it haha. Thanks for your help.

Comment: aaaand that's another one that I do all the time. My first programming instructor called it the "Freshman Dream/"

Answer (score 0):

Totally found the answer myself! It, in fact, was a syntax error.

```
if (($band_name === "") OR ($genre === "") OR ($band_photo === "") OR ($band_bio = ""))
```

The variable `$band_bio` was being assigned to a blank string in the if statement since I accidentally used an assignment operator rather than a comparison operator. So the correct code would need to be `$band_bio === ""` rather than `$band_bio = ""`.

I swear, the problem is always something so much simpler than you think it's going to be.